# How to make my form write out to an excel sheet while automatically breaking to a new empty row

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop, office-automation

I am trying to get text boxes from my Windows Form to write to an excel sheet, but breaking to the next empty row and doing the same thing. I just need Column A-D in each row filled in. with A = tbname.Text, B = tbphone.Text, C =  ddisue.Text, D = lbdate.Text. Then breaking to row 2 A-D for the next customers info. The form is a kiosk that lets customers input this info and it resets for the next person. My only problem now is getting this data into excel. The excel sheet is saved to C:\Users\Willi\OneDrive\Desktop\log\form.xlsx

I can write to static cells however it overwrites once I click submit on the form again.

This is my current output of the data when a cust fills out the form. This is just a notepad.txt that receives the data.

```
  private void btnnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string filepath = @"C:\Users\Willi\OneDrive\Desktop\" + "\\log\\" + "\\dropoff\\" + tbname.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString(" MM-dd-yyyy   s") + ".txt";
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath);
            using (writer)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(" MM-dd-yyyy -HH-mm-ss"));
                writer.WriteLine("NAME: " + tbname.Text);
                writer.WriteLine("ORGANIZATION: " + tborg.Text);
                writer.WriteLine("PHONE: " + tbphone.Text);
                writer.WriteLine("ISSUE: " + ddissue.Text + "  " + tbissue.Text);


            }


            //
        

        }
```

Comment: Rather than using [Interop.Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia), you may consider using NuGet package [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK#related-tools) (or `ClosedXml`).

Comment: That sounds interesting, would you have any examples on how to accomplish my task with that package?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I would encourage you to work with a `.csv` file first. Usually you do not need excel directly and working with a csv file is easier. The conversion to excel is then straightforward.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Well I've just tried writing to a single cell and that's good and worked however If new customer fills out the form it overwrites the previous data.
I have made no progress on finding the next available empty row for the next customers data after they fill out the form.

Comment: @Jazz. I appreciate the feedback. I will check it out if I can't get interop to do my task. I also have saw and installed EPPlus If anyone knows a method with this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the help from a friend and completed my issue.

```
     using ClosedXML.Excel;

     var serials = new List<string>();

        if (tbserial1.Text != "") serials.Add(tbserial1.Text);
        if (tbserial2.Text != "") serials.Add(tbserial2.Text);
        if (tbserial3.Text != "") serials.Add(tbserial3.Text);
        if (tbserial4.Text != "") serials.Add(tbserial4.Text);
        if (tbserial5.Text != "") serials.Add(tbserial5.Text);
        if (tbserial6.Text != "") serials.Add(tbserial6.Text);
        if (tbserial7.Text != "") serials.Add(tbserial7.Text);
        if (tbserial8.Text != "") serials.Add(tbserial8.Text);
        if (tbserial9.Text != "") serials.Add(tbserial9.Text);
        if (tbserial10.Text != "") serials.Add(tbserial10.Text);


        using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\log\\form.xlsx"))
        {
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();

            for (var i = serials.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var serial = serials[i];

                var row = worksheet.LastRowUsed().RowNumber() + 1;
                worksheet.Cell($"A{row}").Value = tbname.Text;
                worksheet.Cell($"B{row}").Value = ddissue.Text;
                worksheet.Cell($"C{row}").Value = lbdate.Text;
                worksheet.Cell($"E{row}").Value = serial;

                worksheet.Cell($"G{row}").Value = tbticket2.Text;
                worksheet.Cell($"H{row}").Value = tbphone.Text;

            }

            workbook.Save();
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).